Understanding Conditional Probability Intuitively
I am new to Probability, and I was trying to solve this problem-
The Jack of Spades (with cider), Jack of Hearts (with tarts), Queen of Spades (with a wink), and Queen of Hearts (without tarts) are taken from a deck of cards. These four cards are shuffled, and then two are dealt.

Find the probability that both of these two cards are queens, given that the first card dealt is a queen.
Find the probability that both are queens, given that at least one is a queen.
Find the probability that both are queens, given that one is the Queen of Hearts.

My Approach
For Part-1, I solved the problem in two ways- Direct(by intuition) and by formula
Formula Approach
A: both queens 
B: first card is queen
$$
 P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} 
$$
$$
 P(A|B) = \frac{\frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{4}} 
$$
So, we got 1/3 as probability.
Issue in Part-1 
When approaching this problem intuitively using conditional probability, we consider a set of 4 possibilities: (QQ, QJ, JQ, JJ). Given event B, our set is reduced to the following cases: (QQ, QJ).
P(A|B) = 1/2 
Although I recognize that my approach is incorrect, I’m struggling to understand the error in my reasoning.
Part-2
A: both queens 
B: at least one is a queen
My answer is correct-
$$
 P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} 
$$
$P(A,B) \text{ is reduced to } P(A) $
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)}{1-P(B)}$$
$$P(A|B) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{6}{5}$$
The probability i got is 1/5
Part-C
A: both queens 
B: given that one is the Queen of Hearts
If I try to approach this problem intuitively as well, The reasoning is as follows:-
Our set of 4 possibilities: (QQ, QJ, JQ, JJ). Given event B, our set is reduced to the following cases: (QQ, QJ, JQ).
So the probability is 1/3, which is correct.
I’m trying to understand why my intuition led me to an incorrect answer in part 1 (where I got 1/2 instead of the correct 1/3). Although my intuition worked correctly for part 3, I’m still uncertain. Additionally, I couldn’t intuitively arrive at the answer for part 2. Could someone guide me in building a better intuition?

Probabilities are equal to ratios of counts only when those items being counted are equally likely to occur.  You seem to have completely ignored the fact that there are multiple distinct queens here at play.  For QJ for instance you have $Q\heartsuit,J\heartsuit$ as well as $Q\heartsuit,J\spadesuit$, and $Q\spadesuit,J\heartsuit$ and $Q\spadesuit,J\spadesuit$.  Four different ways... Meanwhile QQ was only either $Q\heartsuit,Q\spadesuit$ vs $Q\spadesuit,Q\heartsuit$.  Only two ways.  Of your possibilities, QJ can occur twice as many ways as QQ can and as such is more likely.

There are only two outcomes to playing the lottery, you win or you lose... but you don't win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

@JMoravitz Thank you so much for your feedback. I understand where I went wrong and how to improve my approach.

You are trying to use simple counting methods for your “intuitive” approaches. But probability problems work on probabilities. A counting approach is valid only when each outcome you count has equal probability.
There are six equally likely pairs of cards to be dealt. But since your first problem mentions the first card dealt, you also have to consider the order in which the cards are dealt: $\spadesuit$Q then $\heartsuit$Q is different from
$\heartsuit$Q then $\spadesuit$Q.
One way to visualize the twelve equally likely outcomes: first you deal one of four cards, each equally likely; then you deal a card from the remaining three, each equally likely.
In part 1 you start with a queen. There are six deals that start this way. Among those six deals there are two that have both queens. So the probability is $2$ of $6,$ that is, $1/3.$
In part 2 there are ten outcomes with at least one queen: everything except the two outcomes with two jacks. So the conditional probability is $2$ of $10,$ that is, $1/5.$
In part 3 there are six outcomes that include the queen of hearts: three where it is dealt first and three where it is dealt second. Two of these have two queens. So again you have two out of six equally likely outcomes, so $1/3.$
Why did your faulty intuition give the correct probability in that last case? Consider the fact that there are only a limited number of different conditional probabilities you can get from such a small sample space. Every once in a while a wrong method will give a correct result by coincidence.

@DavidK-Thank you so much for your detailed and clear solution! I have a follow-up question regarding the intuition behind Part B. When we're given that at least one queen is drawn, we can simplify P(A,B) to P(A) because knowing B occurred makes A and B dependent. However, in Parts 1 and 3, even if we know B occurred, A and B remain independent. Is this the correct understanding? If possible, could you provide an example to illustrate this distinction?

A and B are not independent in any of the examples here.
